# Is there a good way to access the "model" attribute for a ListView in Django so that it can be used in a template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

thanks in advance for the help. Long story short, I'm attempting to build a CRM-type application in Django (think of it as a Salesforce clone, if you're familiar). I want to be able to access the `model` attribute that I'm providing to my `ExampleListView` class. I'm reading through the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) on the `ListView` class but either can't find how to do it, or I'm just missing the connection.

For context here's some example code (what I've got so far isn't far off of the boilerplate from the docs):

views.py:

```python
class ExampleListView(ListView):
    model = Example
```

app/templates/app/example_list.html:

```html
{% block content %}
<h2>Examples</h2> <!-- Ideally, I'd love to be able to create this dynamically -->
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
         {% for header in ???? %} <!-- Here's what I can't figure out -->
             <th>{{header}}</th>
         {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           {% for example in object_list %}
               --- Display record data here ---
           {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

I've thought about the idea of trying to add the `model` attribute to the context dictionary, but I'm unsure how to go about it. Am I on the right track?

Comment: What you try to do already exists: `django-tables2`: https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even you can add this in your model, may be this is helpful.

```
class ExampleListView(ListView):
    model = Example
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['model'] = Example
```

please revert if it is not helpful I will update the answer accordingly.